# VB.net gridview showing more data than I want it to

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

My gridview is showing more than one ProductName column and the ProductID column as well. All I want it to show is the Product Name clickable column. Can someone help me figure out what code to exclude?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<br /><br /><br />
<asp:linkbutton id="btnAll" runat="server" text="ALL" onclick="btnAll_Click" />
<asp:repeater id="rptLetters" runat="server" datasourceid="dsLetters">
<headertemplate> | </headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
<asp:linkbutton id="btnLetter" runat="server" 
onclick="btnLetter_Click" text='<%#Eval("Letter")%>' />
</itemtemplate>

<separatortemplate> | </separatortemplate>
</asp:repeater>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsLetters" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"
selectcommand="SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ProductName, 1) AS [Letter] FROM [Product]">
</asp:sqldatasource>

<asp:gridview id="gvProducts" runat="server" datakeynames="ProductID"
datasourceid="dsProductLookup" style="margin-top: 12px;">
<Columns>
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductID"
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Product/Default.aspx?ID={0}" 
 DataTextField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" 
 SortExpression="ProductName" />
</Columns>

</asp:gridview>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsProductLookup" runat="server" 
connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"
selectcommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM [Product] ORDER BY [ProductName]">
</asp:sqldatasource>

</asp:Content>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Protected Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    gvProducts.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnLetter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btnLetter As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
    If btnLetter Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    dsProductLookup.SelectCommand = [String].Format("SELECT ProductID, ProductName
    FROM [Product] WHERE ([ProductName] LIKE '{0}%') ORDER BY [ProductName]",
    btnLetter.Text)
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the attribute `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.  Otherwise the `GridView` looks at your data source and automatically adds columns to itself based on the properties of your data source objects.